# How can I balance two weighted assessments for final grades?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I am trying to establish possible points for a graded assignment in which I gave students a choice for the type of assessment. **I want both of the assessment types to be worth the same amount of the final grade.** For fairness, I will excuse the student from the option that they did not choose.

Let's establish some terms. Use **K** for Knowledge, which is **50%** of the final grade. Use **W** for Writing, which is **15%** of the final grade. Points possible for the assessment may be represented as **P** or a numerical value (20?).

If I determine the points possible for the **W** assessment as **20**, how many points possible should the **K** assessment be worth?

Comment: What you have written seems contradictory.  If you have two assignments that the students choose from and want either to count a certain amount of the final grade, the points possible on each assignment should be the same.  Later you talk of assessments-are these parts of the grades of each assignment?  How are assignments and assessments related?  Please review your question and clarify.

Comment: What happened to the other 35% of the final grade?

Comment: Ross - I apologize I used assignments and assessments interchangeably. I am dealing with grading categories that are worth different amounts of the final grade. These have been set up by my school.

Comment: @MrsSnider, now I could be misinterpreting your question, but if you have grading categories like **K** and **W** and they have weighted percentages, the point totals in each category don't matter. For example, if you had 200 points or 2 points for **K**, whatever percentage that student earns will be worth 50 percent of the final grade. If they earn 1.8/2 points or 180/200 points, this is still 50 percent of the final grade. Thus you couldn't what you'd like to do if the percentages for each category is already set.

Comment: To Michael, our grading system is set up as 50% Knowledge & Thinking, 15% Written Communication, 15% Oral Communication, 10% Collaboration, 10% Agency (effort & on-time). Throughout the semester, other assignments such as presentations, quizzes, and experiment logs consider a mixture of all of these learning outcomes. For this, the students chose to write an essay or do a multiple-choice test.

Comment: @MrsSnider Yes this makes sense now – one point earned in the **K** category, in order to have the same impact on a student's grade, means that you have to have $\frac{10}{3}$ points in **W**. That proportion yields T. Gunn's final answer.

Comment: @MrsSnider I have a very important note though – the impact on their grade depends on their grade in each category because of the weighting. Let's say I had an 100% in the **K** category but 0% in the **W** category. If I took this final and took the one that's in the knowledge category and scored an 100%, my grade would not be affected at all. But if I get 100% on the final and it's in the writing category, my grade will be significantly affected. So I don't know if this is the approach you want - you may be better off having a final exam category and marking the one they didn't do as exempt.

Comment: @rb616 Sorry for the late response, but I did end up doing as you suggested. I set up a final exam category (with the exemptions) in my gradebook so the final would be weighted appropriately compared to the rest of the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowledge and Writing are in a ratio of $50:15$. Or, dividing by $15$, a ratio of $\tfrac{10}{3}:1$. Noting that **K** counts more, we know that this means that every $1$ point in **K** counts for $\frac{10}3$ in **W** (because the other way around wouldn't make sense). So to use the same units (those of **W**) the question is $x$ units of **K** $= \frac{10}{3}x$ units of **W** $= 20$ units of **W**. That is $$\frac{10}{3}x = 20.$$ To solve for $x$ we multiply both sides by the reciprocal, yielding $$x = \frac{3}{10}20 = 6.$$